# Any way to compare activity of SE sites?

Tags: discussion, support, specific-question

I would like to compare `activity` or statistics for some sites let's say wordpress and drupal.

Is there any way how I can do that?

I was looking for some "number" on within the site itself....

Comment: You can write a query to fetch each site's raw numbers from the [Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/) and then bring the two exported tables into the analytical tool of your choice. What specifically are you looking to compare?

Comment: Want to know how many questions/answers, users etc is for each system (wodpress/drupal) to give me some idea on which one is more "used". I know I know the data won't be 'accurate' but I wanted to have some idea. I thought this would be easy to access...

Comment: You don't even need the Explorer for that. Just look at the Stack Exchange [list of sites](http://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#technology-traffic). Drupal has 12K questions, 16K answers, and 6.4K users. WordPress has 20K / 27K / 13K.

Comment: Thanks for the question. I wanted to know the activity a specific site has, with Data Explorer this is no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want to see is today's snapshot, just look at Stack Exchange's [list of sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#technology-traffic). For example:

```
site     | questions answers users
---------| -----------------------
Drupal   |       12K     16K    6K  
WordPress|       20K     27K   13K
```

If, however, you want something deeper, then you may want to check the [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/). I wrote this query to dump the [number of questions per day](https://data.stackexchange.com/drupal%20answers/query/69783/number-of-questions-asked-per-date). I downloaded a CSV for both sites and then plotted their moving averages against each other:

[image: WordPress vs Drupal]

There's a wealth of raw data available for usage statistics across the SE sites.

Answer (score 1):

The Stack Exchange hub has a [list of the SE sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list), along with basic statistics for them all. Beyond that, moderators and SE staff have access to such information, but it is generally not disclosed to the general public without good cause.